# O que significa “aceder” que os portugueses usam?

Tags: significado, cultura

O que significa “aceder” que os portugueses(Portugal) usam?

Comment: Sua pergunta serveria como resposta dessa pergunta: [O que é considerado pleonasmo?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/150/3) :)

Comment: @Math ... e serviu mesmo!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O uso mais comum na web portuguesa tem o sentido de "acessar".

Porém o verbo também tem outros sentidos:

- *concordar*, *anuir*, *assentir*
- *resignar-se*
- *acrescer*, *ajuntar*

#### Fontes

https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/aceder
http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/aceder