# O que é considerado pleonasmo?

Tags: pleonasmo

Em alguns casos, hoje em dia, as pessoas são acusadas de cometer pleonasmo quando se referem a algo usando palavras diferentes que contêm o mesmo significado. Eu gostaria de saber ao certo o que exatamente é considerado pleonasmo, e o que não é.

## Exemplo

> Vamos subir lá para cima.

Comment: Talvez seja uma duplicata de http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/87/entrar-pra-dentro-sair-pra-fora-subir-pra-cima-e-cair-pra-baixo (como disse "talvez")

Comment: "Pleonasmo" é uma figura de linguagem, portanto algo que diz respeito a *estilo* de escrita, onde as "regras" são bem mais frouxas. Você está se referindo aos pleonasmos que não são aceitos nunca (ou quase), conhecidos como "pleonasmos viciosos".

Answer (score 10):

Conforme a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_pleonasmos) (a página original foi apagada na Wikipédia, mas existe uma similar na [EverybodyWiki](https://pt.everybodywiki.com/Lista_de_pleonasmos)):

> Esta é uma lista de alguns exemplos de pleonasmos viciosos
> (redundâncias) usados na língua portuguesa. Pleonasmo pode ser tanto
> uma figura de linguagem quanto um vício de linguagem. O pleonasmo é
> uma redundância (proposital ou não) em uma expressão, enfatizando-a.

### Pleonasmos Viciosos

Esta secção mostra apenas alguns exemplos de pleonasmos viciosos, aqui não estão localizados todos.

| Pleonasmo | Significado |
| --- | --- |
| Cego dos olhos. | Se está cego, é do olho. |
| Bate palmas com as mãos. | Se vai bater palmas, é com as mãos. |
| Climatologia geográfica. | Se é climatologia, só pode ser geográfica. |
| De chapéu na cabeça. | Se está de chapéu, o adorno só pode estar na cabeça. |
| Maluco da cabeça. | Se está maluco, só pode ser da cabeça. |
| Subir para cima. | Se está subindo, só pode ser para cima. |
| Descer para baixo. | Se está descendo, é para baixo. |
| Entrar para dentro. | Se está entrando, é para dentro. |
| Sair para fora. | Se está saindo, é para fora. |
| Hemorragia de sangue. | A hemorragia já é um derramamento de sangue para fora dos vasos. |
| Unanimidade de todos. | Se é unânime se trata de todos. |
| Acabamento final. | Se é um acabamento, só pode ser final. |
| Amanhecer o dia. | Se está a amanhecer, só pode ser o dia. |
| Surpresa inesperada. | Se é uma surpresa, logo, será inesperada. |
| Conviver juntos. | Se uma pessoa está convivendo com outra, só pode ser juntos. |
| Decapitar a cabeça. | Se vai decapitar, só pode ser a cabeça. |
| Encarar de frente. | Se a pessoa está encarando, só pode ser de frente. |
| Gritar alto. | Se uma pessoa grita, só pode ser alto. |
| Certeza absoluta. | Se uma pessoa tem certeza, ela só pode ser absoluta. |
| Cheirar com o nariz. | Se uma pessoa cheira, tem que ser com o nariz. |
| Elo de ligação. | Se é um elo, apenas é de ligação. |
| Dupla de dois. | Se é dupla, tem que ser de dois. |
| Verdade verdadeira. | Se é uma verdade, só pode ser verdadeira (verídica). |
| Olhar com os olhos. | Se uma pessoa está olhando, só pode ser com os olhos. |
| Lamber com a língua. | Se a pessoa lambe, só é possível com a língua. |
| Isto é um fato real. | Se é fato, é real. |
| Multidão de pessoas. | Se é uma multidão, só pode ser de pessoas. |
| Morder com os dentes. | Se a pessoa morde, só pode ser com os dentes. |
| Estreia pela primeira vez. | Se é uma estreia, tem que ser a primeira vez. |
| Panorama geral. | Se é um panorama, vai ser uma abordagem geral. |
| Prefiro mais. | Se você prefere algo, é óbvio que irá gostar mais daquilo. |
| Mais melhor. | Se alguma coisa é melhor, obviamente será mais conveniente. |
| Ganhar de graça. | Se você ganha alguma coisa, ela é de graça. Se não fosse, seria uma compra. |
| Criar novas. | Se você cria alguma coisa, logo ela é nova. |
| Própria autobiografia. | A autobiografia é a sua própria biografia. |
| Há muitos anos atrás. | Se algo ocorreu há muitos anos, certamente será do pretérito. |
| Países do mundo. | Os países estão localizados no mundo (planeta). |
| Viúvo(a) do(a) falecido(a). | Se ela é viúva, seu marido está falecido. |
| Fato verídico. | Se é um fato, é algo verdadeiro. Se é verdadeiro, é verídico. |
| Almirante da Marinha. | Só existe essa espécie de patente na marinha. |
| Demente mental. | A demência é uma deficiência que afeta a mentalidade. |
| Decapitar (ou guilhotinar) a cabeça). | Se você decapita alguém, está retirando a cabeça desse sujeito. |
| Suicidou(-se) a si mesmo. | Se alguém se suicida, ele o mata. |
| Comer com a boca. | Se você está comendo alguma coisa, só é possível com a boca. |
| Andar os pés. | Se andamos, utilizamos os pés. |
| Adiar para depois. | Se algo está sendo adiado, ele ficará para depois. |
| 24 horas por dia. | Um dia tem somente 24 horas. |
| Comparecer pessoalmente. | Se você comparece, apresenta-se em um local. Mas atualmente, devido à tecnologia de Internet, é possível comparecer à distância, como em caso de Videoconferência. |
| Conclusão final. | Se é conclusão, está no epílogo. |
| Mar salgado. | Se é mar, tem sua água salgada. |
| Surdo do ouvido. | Se alguém é surdo é porque o ouvido não funciona bem. |
| Arder em chamas. | Se algo está em chamas, tem de estar a arder. |

### Pleonasmo em ênfase

Alguns autores, escritores e cantores usaram pleonasmos literários e viciosos em suas obras.

| Pleonasmo | Autor/Escritor/Cantor |
| --- | --- |
| "*Detalhes* tão *pequenos* de nós dois." | Roberto Carlos |
| "Ó mar *salgado*, quanto do teu *sal*. São lágrimas de Portugal." | Fernando Pessoa |
| "O cadáver de um *defunto morto* que já *faleceu*." | Roberto Gómez Bolaños |
| "Eu nasci, *há dez mil anos atrás*." | Raul Seixas |
| "Foi o que *vi com meus próprios olhos*." | Antonio Calado |
| "A *ameaça*, o *perigo*, eu os apalpava quase." | Guimarães Rosa |

### Pleonasmo em complemento verbal

Alguns pleonasmos são complementos verbais de verbos intransitivos. Eles são usados para aplicar características ao substantivo implícito de um verbo

| Pleonasmo | Autor/Escritor/Cantor |
| --- | --- |
| "*Sorriu* para Holanda um *sorriso* ainda marcado de pavor." | Viana Moog |
| "*Chovia* uma triste *chuva* de resignação." | Manuel Bandeira |
| "E *rir* meu *riso* e derramar meu pranto." | Vinícius de Morais |
| "*Morrerás morte* vil na mão de um forte." | Gonçalves Dias |
| "Eu *canto* um *canto* matinal." | Guilherme de Almeida |

Comment: E bater palmas com os pés, não?

Comment: **"O pleonasmo é uma redundância (proposital ou não) em uma expressão, enfatizando-a."** Logo, bater palmas com os pés não é possível e muito menos redundante, então não é pleonasmo.

Comment: Estava a brincar brincando, pois "se vai bater palmas é com as mãos", a não ser que as bata com os pés ;P

Comment: Ah bom... hahahaha... as vezes é difícil entender as ironias nos comentários. Mas essa é uma expressão que, não vou negar, já utilizei, mesmo sendo logicamente errada.

Answer (score 9):

Qualquer redundância semântica é considerada um pleonasmo.

- Subir para cima
- Descer para baixo
- Sair para fora
- Entrar para dentro
- Repetir de novo

Não se trata exatamente de um erro. Muito da poesia e da literatura se baseia fortemente no pleonasmo para criar ênfase e expressão. Já no texto formal, como em reportagens, entrevistas, dissertações e monografias, torna-se desnecessário. Nestes casos, é considerado como fora de contexto.

Existem também pessoas que ficam incomodadas de ouvir o pleonasmo na fala coloquial, durante uma conversa. Para estes, não há muito remédio. A língua é falada do jeito que as pessoas falam.

Comment: Mais alguns exemplos de pleonasmo:  
  
- Cego dos olhos
- Hemorragia de sangue
- Acabamento final
- Surpresa inesperada
- Gritar alto

Answer (score 5):

Quando fazemos uso de expressões redundantes com a finalidade de reforçar uma idéia estamos utilizando a figura de linguagem chamada **pleonasmo**.

Exemplos:

*Vai ir*.

*Os portugueses de Portugal*. @Math :D

*Joana sofre de leucemia no sangue*.

Comment: (Acho que "vai ir" é gramaticalmente incorreto.)

Comment: É certamente comum, @ANeves. Entendo que não agrada todos os ouvidos, mas assim como se diz "ele vai jogar", se diz também "ele vai ir" — o primeiro "ir" é um auxiliar de futuro.

Answer (score 4):

De acordo com o Priberam, "[pleonasmo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pleonasmo)" é a repetição de uma ideia na mesma frase.

Assim sendo, sempre que na mesma frase se transmite uma ideia múltiplas vezes,  estamos a cometer um pleonasmo.

**Exemplo**

> vi com os meus olhos

Já sabemos que uma pessoa vê com os olhos, logo, ao adicionarmos "com os meus olhos" estamos a cometer um pleonasmo.

Normal:

> Vi o João a copiar.

Pleonasmo:

> Vi **com os meus olhos** o João a copiar.